# Why can't I get this initialized?

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

I have been trying to figure this out for DAYS. I am a beginner, so please bear with me. I have read a bunch of articles on delegation but I still just don't get it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Header

```
@protocol MidiInit <NSObject>
@end


@interface CBAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) id midiDelegate;

-(id) initWithDelegate :(id <MidiInit>) delegate;

@end
```

Implementation

```
@synthesize midiDelegate;

-(id) initWithDelegate:(id<MidiInit>)delegate
{
if ((self = [super init]))
{
    self.midiDelegate = delegate;
    midi = [[MidiClass alloc] initWithDelegate://not sure what to put here];
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Create a delegate for your MidiClass?

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know what you are trying to achieve, but from what you're showing us, pretty much everything looks wrong :-)

Are you showing us the application delegate? If so, what is the point of delegating to another delegate from the application delegate? It doesn't look like a standard approach.

Second, you probably don't want a 'strong' reference to a delegate, could lead to memory leaks.

But honestly, I don't think the real problem here is what you're pointing too, the entire approach seems to be wrong. Tell us more about what you're trying to achieve and I'll try to update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I have a MIDI class that I am trying to initialize with a delegate as per the class author's recommendation.